# Content dispute lock on a question effectively clears close votes

Tags: discussion

Recently, I encountered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64109611/callback-function-dosent-execute) where the OP repeatedly vandalized the post. The un-vandalized version was not very good and received two close votes for having too much code. In the meantime, the rollback war, mod flags, and comment flags lead to a diamond imposing a 7-day content dispute lock, suspending the OP to cool down, and cleaning up almost the entire comment thread (which, by that time, had become rather heated).

I think that all three actions were entirely appropriate in the circumstances, but the content dispute lock did have the odd effect of effectively clearing the close votes, since they will [age away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away) after 4 days if I read the linked Meta post correctly.

In this case, what is the correct moderation action and system behavior? For example, since the OP was suspended for 7 days, was the 7-day content dispute lock redundant? I assume that suspended users can't continue to edit their posts, but am I incorrect about that point?

Which leads to my question: what should happen in cases like this? For example:

- Should the diamond have casted the third close vote prior to locking?
- Should the post have been locked for the same duration as the OP's suspension (and long enough for the close votes to age away)?
- Should the system consider the content lock and "not count" that towards the close votes aging away?

Thoughts for how to handle this edge case?

Comment: *Should the diamond have casted the third close vote prior to locking?* Unless the question is clear cut close-worthy to everyone, not just subject matter experts, I'm pretty sure this is not appropriate

Comment: @TheMaster At the same time, the lock all but guarantees that the question will not be closed, so effectively the diamond decided that it should not be closed (whether that was the intended effect or not).